# Parsing out content from HTML using regex?

Tags: html, regex

How can I use regex to find everything except for data within div with a specific style? e.g.

```
<div style="float:left;padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px">
    <img src="../Style/BreadCrumbs/Divider.png">
</div>
<div style="float:left; padding-top:5px;">
    Data to keep
</div>
<div style="float:left;padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px">
    <img src="../Style/BreadCrumbs/Divider.png">
</div>
```

I want regex to match everything except for the data. The best way I can see is to just remove the html markup and combine the files afterwards with vb (I already have the code for vb.)

I'm using regex because I need to extract the data from several hundred files.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Why do you think a regex is the right tool?

Comment: Provide some html to parse. And ignore all the crap you're going to hear about not parsing html with regex, it's perfectly applicable in simple cases ;)

Comment: If you can make strong assumptions about the content of the div, you can extract it, but you need to specify those assumptions here, along with an example.

Comment: Any particular flavour of RegEx?

Comment: The flavour can maybe be "POSIX ERE" (Notepad++)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suggested method is probably not a good way to do this. If:

- you have access to `grep`
- your version of  grep supports perl-compatible regex (`PCRE`)
- this style of `div` only wraps your data, not other elements
- the 'data' `div` does not contain other `div`s

Then you can use:

```
(?s)<div style="float:left; padding-top:5px;">.*?</div>
```

The important parts of this are:

- `(?s)` which activates `DOTALL`, which means that `.` will match newlines
- `.*?` which matches the contents of the div reluctantly, which means it'll stop at the first `</div>` it finds.

To use this, you'll need to activate a few grep options:

```
grep -Pzo $PATTERN file
```

For these:

- `-P` activates the `PCRE`
- `-z` replaces `\n` by `NUL` so grep will treat the entire file as a single line
- `-o` prints only the matching parts

After this you'll need to strip off the divs. `sed` is a good tool for this.

```
sed 's|</\?div[^>]*>||g'
```

If you put all of your files in one directory you can do the joining at the same time:

```
grep -Pzo $PATTERN *.html | sed 's|</\?div[^>]*>||g' > out.html
```

Comment: @sas Welcome to SO! A common way to say thanks here is by up-voting the answer, and accepting by clicking the check-mark (if it's the best answer.)