# How to grep multiple lines from a HTML page

Tags: html, shell, grep

I have a HTML page with lot of  tags like this

```
<tr>
 <td> a </td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td> a </td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td> a </td>
</tr>
```

I need to grep all these blocks alone leaving all other content (like    general text).

I saw some other post on pcregrep, but it was not clear to me.

Can somebody help me with grep (or any other solution) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed` to get all these blocks:

```
$ sed -n '/<tr>/,/<\/tr>/p' input.html
<tr>
 <td> a </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td> a </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td> a </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: this extracts all the things between the first <tr> and the last </tr>. if OP wants only <tr/> blocks, this solution my have problem. e.g. <tr><td>...</td></tr><!-- text not needed --><tr><td>...</td></tr>

Comment: If `<tr>` and `</tr>` are always on separated lines, this command works.

Comment: forget it.. it is really hard to bring code format in comment. tired to make the comment look better. solve this could be more difficult than the original question.. I give up.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9485037/320220). Basically you use `grep`s `-z` option plus a very specific regex.